# How to Install ClockworkMod on Innos A35

Tags: installation, clockworkmod-recovery, rom-manager

I tried to install ClockworkMod via ROM manager. My device(Innos A35) wasn't listed, but I chose one that was on the list thinking that it would somehow get installed. There was a download, but when I reboot to recovery mode the old recovery software with only a few options is shown. I was thinking that rebooting to recovery mode would bring up something like [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/ClockworkMod_Recovery) if ClockworkMod was properly installed. Can someone point to me what could be wrong? Or can someone tell me how to manually install ClockworkMod without using ROM Manager?

Comment: If your device isn't in the [supported list](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) then this might not be a good idea anyway (unless there's an unofficial version floating around somewhere for your specific device).

Answer (score 3):

Any recovery, be it ClockworkMod or TWRP, or others, **must** be specifically created for each device (or sometimes device family, if their hardware is similar enough) separately.  Picking a random device off a list in ROM Manager will not work, and may even damage your phone.

Quick [Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=innos+a35+clockworkmod&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=innos+a35+clockworkmod), [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/sitesearch.php?q=innos%20a35), and [Rootzwiki](http://rootzwiki.com/index.php?app=core&module=search&section=search&do=search&fromsearch=1) searches don't bring up any relevant hits for "Innos A35" at all, so it's safe to assume that this device is not supported by any well-known recovery makers.  This may be because the device is too new, or there simply is not enough interest in it from the Android developer community.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any guide on how to customize a recovery software to fit one's own device?

Comment: You need to be fairly knowledgeable in Android development on Linux. There is a very basic guide (for a different device) [here](http://www.twobitcoder.com/?p=158) that you can look at to see if that's something you'd be comfortable with undertaking on your own.