# A few Questions about Recovery

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, root-access

I tried to install ClockworkMod recovery using Rom Manager but my device was not listed on the supported versions. So [I tried installing ClockworkMod for a different device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44800/16575) using the [commands shown here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_fastboot_intro#Installing_recovery_using_fastboot). Now I can't boot into recovery mode, but the phone starts up normally.

So I thought of backing everything up before trying anything more with the phone. I found [this guide](http://www.twobitcoder.com/?p=102) which has instructions on how to back everything up. But my filesystem doesn't have a file /proc/mtd as mentioned there.

1. Can someone point out a way for me to find those partitions?
2. After searching the file system in the phone I came across a file `/cache/recovery/last_log`. Thinking that the file would prove to be useful I have added the contents in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cqFyLrai). Can someone explain to me the contents of the file and how it can be useful to accomplish what is [mentioned here?](http://www.twobitcoder.com/?p=102)
3. As I have mentioned earlier, due to my efforts to install ClockWorkMod recovery, the phone doesn't boot to recovery mode. Is there a way to use the mentioned data in order to fix that? (Maybe backup the data as mentioned in the link and restore them using some terminal commands using adb?)
4. After looking at the contents, I tired the command `busybox mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p16 /mnt/sdcard/recovery-test` and it returned the error `mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p16 on /mnt/sdcard/recovery-test failed: Invalid argument` Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: @John Innos A35 http://www.innos.com/en/productinfo.aspx?id=1

Comment: To get your recovery working again you must flash a compatible recovery image. This part was already covered with [your original question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44800/16575). There's no way you can "fix" the incompatible CWM. Check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for possible sources, or check the manufacturer's website.